# VarChar to NVarChar and back

Tags: clr, sql-server-2012, varchar, nvarchar

The environment is SQL Server 2012. I'm about to change a clr procedure returned result column from `varchar` to `nvarchar`, but I'm not sure if the characters which can be found in `varchar` code page will always convert to the same character in unicode and also the other way. The bad example would be if someone would get the results from procedure with column of `nvarchar` and put that in database with `varchar` column. The question is, will they convert correctly always?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VARCHAR is specific to your system codepage. NVARCHAR holds Unicode characters. Unicode is always going to be a superset of any legacy codepage. As such, you can expect your conversions from VARCHAR -> NVARCHAR to map properly. However, if your NVARCHAR string later contains Unicode characters that are not found in your legacy codepage, the characters will be lost when converting back to VARCHAR.

When possible, you should avoid this type of conversion. Update the table column to NVARCHAR.

Comment: Yes this is what I wanted to hear. I thought so my self but wanted to hear an opinion. The thing is there could be logic using this procedure, but that is there fault for not working properly with nvarchar. The procedure is meant for csv string conversion to relation, but in input there can also be Unicode only characters and this conversion is necessary. That`s that.